# Differential equation:$y'=a-2b \sin(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

About the following ODE:

$y=y(t), y(0)=0$

$y'=a-2b\sin{y}$

I know that there exists a constant $c$ which satisfis $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}  y(t)=c$ when $2b\geq a$.

But, when $2b < a$, I don't understand the solution of $y(t)$.

**I  especially want to know the value of  $\cfrac{y(T)-y(T/2)}{T/2}$ for large enough $T$**.

Comment: Are $a,b$ supposed to be positive?

Comment: Yes.$a,b$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

If $a > 2b>0$, then $y' \ge a - 2b > 0$ for all $t$, so the solution is strictly increasing.

The equation is separable, and the solution can be written implicitly as

$$ t = \int_0^y \dfrac{ds}{a-2b \sin(s)}$$

In particular, the time to go from $y=0$ to $2\pi$ is
$$ \tau = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{ds}{a-2b \sin(s)} $$
which happens to be $$ \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-4b^2}}$$
and by periodicity of $\sin$, the time to go from any $y_1$ to $y_1 + 2\pi$ is also $\tau$.

If $T$ is large, $y(T) - y(T/2) \approx \pi T/\tau$ so
$$ \frac{y(T) - y(T/2)}{T/2} \approx \frac{2\pi}{\tau} = \sqrt{a^2-4b^2}$$

Comment: I get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$\frac{\frac{dy(x)}{dx}}{a-2b\sin(y(x))}=1$$